# Where Can I Download Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1?

Tags: windows, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a universal Windows App with WinJS. I've downloaded the latest update to VS2013. The RC version. I've installed all the SDKs I can find. I've installed the WinLibJS_VSE.exe extension, as well. Funny thing about that one is that VS updates keeps saying that I didn't...

When I open up any of the sample universal WinJS apps - like the ones here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Universal-Windows-app-cb3248c3 - I always end up with this error:

```
Could not find SDK "Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1, Version=1.0". C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

I tried finding this SDK on my machine, but I'm not finding it at all. Nor am I finding it online. I copied some SDKs from `C:\Program Files (x86) into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just for sure, can you create new WP8.1 projects in VS, either in C# or HTML? Or there is only problem in opening existing samples.

Comment: Such an error message would never have the phrase "SDK" in the message text.  Post the **exact** message.

Comment: Existing samples. I can't create a JS WP8.1 project. Only C#. Probably because these are not installed or not installed correctly, etc. Where are they?

Hans, is it not obvious that I copy-pasted? That's what it says exactly.

Comment: Was any solution found here? i having the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final release of Visual Studio seems to have resolved this issue.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone SDK should have been installed when you installed the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2 RC.

The files should be located here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\1.0\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\js`

When you create a C# project, is it a Silverlight project or a Windows Runtime project?

Comment: Thanks for the information, Eric. I think I really got the right guy on the case here :)

I don't have a Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1 directory under my ExtensionSDKs. Where can I go to get it? I definitely installed VS 2013 Ultimate Update 2 RC. Maybe I'll try to install it again and "repair" it, etc. I made a universal project with C#, but it's a Silverlight project. I can't make a JS one.

Comment: I assume that you tried the repair and it didn't install the ExtensionSDKs. Can you create a non-Silverlight Universal app - i.e. a Windows Runtime app - using C#? (In Visual Studio, click New Project > expand Visual C# > expand Store Apps > expand Universal Apps > select Blank App, give it a name, etc.) If not, you probably should contact Customer Service.

Comment: I was able to make a portable RT project following those steps, Eric. I received your quick assistance voucher. Thank you very much. I called the number. I've been put on hold a few times and have been repeatedly asked my name, number, email, what product I'm using, etc. I keep asking about the quick assistance voucher. They have no idea what I'm talking about. I'm on hold again while typing this. 42 minutes in and I THINK I'm being set up with a technical person who will call me back "within 8 hours." Reminds me of http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FizzBinTheTechnicalSupportSecretHandshake.aspx

Comment: I got some good help this afternoon. The problem isn't resolved quite yet, though. We're going to try again in the morning. For starters, I needed to have the Hyper V Platform component installed. Then we reinstalled Update 2 RC as well as the VS extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript 1 and 2. Still no dice. He's recommending an uninstall of Update 2 RC and then a reinstall. We'll see how that goes.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, although I'm sorry to hear that your experience was so difficult. I'll follow-up with the customer service team to see how we can improve our responses. Otherwise, please let us know if your uninstall / reinstall process solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'm partly to blame. I answered "Home" to the first question. Big mistake. The uninstall/reinstall did not help. I'm not getting any kind of error message at all during the process. But the extension SDK is not there in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs folder when I'm done, so this is a big red flag. I'm not sure why it's skipping that step. Is there some incompatibility about which I don't know? Some prerequisite?

Comment: I have also tried to uninstall all visual studio applications on my pc (express and VS2013), which took foooorever i might add :P and installed VS2013 with update 2 RC, and still nothing, cannot create a Javascript Universal app :(

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've been talking to the Visual Studio team about this.

Did you happen to install the "Visual Studio 2013 Extensions for the Windows Library for JavaScript"? 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40793
(In the Programs and Features list, it will appear as "Visual Studio Extension for Windows Library for JavaScript".)

If so, you'll need to uninstall it. The order for uninstall is:

1. Visual Studio 2013
2. Visual Studio Update 2 RC
3. "Visual Studio Extension for the Windows Library for JavaScript"

After the uninstall, reinstall in this order:

1. Visual Studio 2013
2. Visual Studio Update 2 RC

Of course, all of this assumes that you've already upgraded your development environment to Windows 8.1. These projects will only work on a Windows 8.1 machine.

I hope that this helps. If not, we can try something else.

Comment: As per my previous comment, I tried this already, but looking today I see I forgot to remove VS 2012 update 3 and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK, so I am removing them now (and should be completely rid of all Visual studio installations), and will report back if it helped. (Takes a long time to do all this, so might take some time)

Comment: Done, and still no luck, just lists Javascript -> Store Apps -> Windows Apps, no Universal, or Windows Phone

Comment: I'll try this later today, too. I did install that extension.

Comment: @Eric: You should merge your two answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I tried all above none of them work. However the following worked for me:

**1-)** Uninstall Visual Studio extensions for Javascript

**2-)** Uninstall visual studio 2013

**3-)** Install visual studio 2013 with Update 2 RC from the following link (it is VS + update 2 bundled)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42303

Above link is for Premium edition. Find the relevant link accoringly.

P.S It is quite lame that when you uninstall Visual studio , it doesn't uninstall some of its addins. And you have lot of remaining artifacts :(

Answer (score 0):

Andy (and potentially others running into this issue)....

We are currently investigating into this issue to understand the root cause. If this issue is blocking you from development, the recommendation is to perform the following steps "carefully". If these steps do not help, then please let us know!

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2013 from Programs and Features
2. Reboot machine if prompted
3. Delete or rename these folders-
   I.    \Documents\Visual Studio 2013
   II.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
   III.  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
   IV.   \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
   V.    \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
   VI.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
   VII.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1
   VIII. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\
   IX.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneAppx\
   X.    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Silverlight Kits
   XI.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits
   XII.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone
   XIII. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneAppx
   XIV.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools
4. Go to the registry editor (start >> run >> regedit) and remove/rename the following registries-
   I.    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
   II.   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
   III.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
   IV.   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config
5. Download the .iso image of Visual Studio 2013 preferably using the relevant MSDN account
6. Extract the .iso file by using an extraction tool, such as WinRar (http://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-401.exe) remember to associate .iso extension with WinRar during its setup
7. Install Visual Studio 2013 using this extracted setup
8. Install the Visual Studio Update 2 RC from here: _http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307
9. Check if the templates are appearing
10. You can then install the Windows Phone standalone SDK from here: _https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk or through the Visual Studio extensions.

Comment: None of the above worked for me. I applied this too, now Windows phone and javascript templates are göne totally. I guess I have reinstall Windows :(