# Trying to Add Windows Phone 8.1 to a Windows 8.1 (HTML/JS) project (Universal app) fails

Tags: windows-8.1, winjs, windows-store, windows-phone-8.1

Im not sure if i missed some information or small print somewhere, but i downloaded the Windows Phone 8.1 dev tools from here: https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
And that now gives me the option to right click on the project to convert it to a "Universal App", but when i click the "Add Windows Phone 8.1..." link, it says two new projects will be added etc, so I press ok then i get the following error:

[image: Error message]

What gives? As it says in the title, this is a Windows Store Javascript/HTML (WinJS) project, so i know this is something new for Windows Phone 8.1, but surely the template should have been added no? i am at a bit of a loss, if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Found another stack with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027200/where-can-i-download-microsoft-phone-winjs-2-1#comment35442942_23027200

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you've installed the Update 2 for Visual Studio: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307 At the time of this post, only the RC version is available (and this link is for VS 2013). You may have already done this, but I mention it since you didn't mention it in your original post.